# How to fix multipass error: list failed: cannot connect to the multipass socket

Tags: debian, snapshot, multipass

I install multipass with the following command on Deepin Linux

```
apt install snapd
snap install multipass
```

but it not work with this error:

```
list failed: cannot connect to the multipass socket
Please ensure multipassd is running and '/var/snap/multipass/common/multipass_socket' is accessible
```

[image]

and there is log

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: no ，i have no idea

Answer (score 10):

The only way I was able to circumvent this issue was doing 
 `sudo chmod a+w /var/snap/multipass/common/multipass_socket`.

If you need `multipass_socket`, follow [these instructions](https://snapcraft.io/docs/parallel-installs)

- `sudo snap set system experimental.parallel-instances=true`
- `sudo snap install multipass_socket`

Comment: but the file (/var/snap/multipass/common/multipass_socket)  is not exists in my PC, and my PC' OS is Deepin Linux V 20.2.2

Comment: @jiker, you can `sudo snap install multipass_socket` if you follow the instructions [here](https://snapcraft.io/docs/parallel-installs)

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR:

1. Check if virtualization is enabled.
2. Restart snapd
3. Restart multipass.multipassd
4. Check running instances using `multipass list`.

- Settings are lost when system restarts.

---

I took several attempts in trying to resolve this. I was following this [basic tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-your-first-snap#3-building-a-snap-is-easy) in initiating snap packages. The issues erupted once I ran `snapcraft`. I'm hoping that the combination of them is what really assisted in the end. For each of the steps below, I ran `snapcraft` to check whether it worked.

PS: I'm running Manjaro's Plasma KDE v22.0.0, V5.97.0.

Firstly ensure that multipass installation was successful with `multipass version`, which should give:

```
multipass   1.10.1
```

If not, run `snap install multipass`.

Additional steps:

1. Ensure VM is enabled in the systems BIOS settings. The error related to this on running `snapcraft` is verbose enough to understand.
2. Restart the snapd service using `sudo systemctl restart snapd`.
3. Restart the multipassd daemons, using

```
sudo snap restart multipass.multipassd
```

3. I attempted [Silva's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67912801/16866123), but I ran into the issue that the directory did not exist. At this point, I was facing the same issue as the OP:

```
Please ensure multipassd is running and '/var/snap/multipass/common/multipass_socket' is accessible
```

I think the solution for this is evidently `multipass start`, which essentially sets up all the directories that may be needed moving forward in my development. Allow some time to pass before running the launch. The restart command. I think the restart command takes some time to fulfill.
After this, I was able to successfully run `snapcraft`, & I did not need to run the `chmod` command to alter access.
You can use `multipass list` to check on running instances of the VM.

A terrible caveat is that these settings are lost when the computer restarts, so it has to be re-configured again.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered a similar issue when I have installed Multipass on **Ubuntu**.

The error message was the same:

> Please ensure multipassd is running and
> '/var/snap/multipass/common/multipass_socket' is accessible

and the socket '/var/snap/multipass/common/multipass_socket' did not exist.

Upon closer inspection of /var/log/syslog

```
cat /var/log/syslog|grep multipass
```

I found this lines:

> multipassd[162758]: #012dnsmasq: directory /etc/resolv.conf for
> resolv-file is missing, cannot poll multipassd[162758]: dnsmasq died:
> Process returned exit code: 5 multipassd[162758]: Caught an unhandled
> exception: dnsmasq died: Process returned exit code: 5

Leading me to think that something is wrong with /etc/resolv.conf

when I looked up /etc/resolv.conf with  `ls -la /etc/resolv.conf` it was a symlink that pointed to  ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

I decided to try and fix resolveconf via reinstall

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall resolvconf
```

and after this i reinstalled multipass with:

```
snap remove multipass
snap install multipass
```

And multipass launch worked for me without a problem.

```
multipass launch
Launched: wise-brill
```

Answer (score 0):

Having encountered this same problem myself, as well as `list failed: Remote "" is unknown or unreachable.`, and not finding a (satisfactory) solution, I've trialed and errored up until the simple solution:

1. Ensure your host can reach `cloud-images.ubuntu.com`
2. Run

```bash
sudo snap restart multipass.multipassd
```

> or it's equivalent: `sudo systemctl restart snap.multipass.multipassd.service`

3. Wait several seconds for it to be ready. If you're too quick, it'll provide the same error.

> You can check if it works with `tail -n50 /var/log/syslog | grep multipass` and see if it mentions `Starting Multipass <version>`. At that point it hasn't encountered any errors at starting up.

#### Cause

Searching the logs, it had an unhandled exception of not being able to reach the host which provides the image manifests. I was messing around with routing, so that problem was to be expected, but it's odd it cannot handle being disconnected.

The problematic log lines are:

```
Jun 13 10:52:22 hostname multipassd[1247]: Could not update manifest: failed to download from 'https://cloud-images.
ubuntu.com/buildd/releases/bionic/release/bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk.img': Host cloud-images.ubuntu.com not found
Jun 13 10:52:22 hostname multipass.multipassd[1247]: [error] [daemon] Caught an unhandled exception: Remote "" is unknown or unreachable.
Jun 13 10:52:22 hostname systemd[1]: snap.multipass.multipassd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after configuring the Google DNS server (8.8.8.8) in the netplan. Removing the DNS settings resolved the problem.

But, I am not sure what exactly is the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I've run the same problem, to my case I noticed that the `snapd.socket` was disabled, and because of that multipasss could't communicate. So to turn on type:

```
sudo systemctl start snapd.scket
```

After that it should be working normally.